# Casting DataRow to Strongly-Typed DataRow: How do they do it?

Tags: c#, casting, strongly-typed-dataset, auto-generate

I'm trying to make a lightweight version of some strongly-typed DataRows in order to write a test for a method that takes `IEnumerable<T> where T : DataRow`.

I would like to make a class that inherits from `DataRow` but has additional properties, as in the autogenerated strongly-typed DataSet.Designer.cs. I cannot get their code to work, and indeed I don't understand how it *could* work:

```cs
// from AnimalDataSet.Designer.cs:
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
public AnimalRow AddAnimalRow(
        string Name, 
        int Species_ID) {
    AnimalRow rowAnimalRow = ((AnimalRow)(this.NewRow()));
    object[] columnValuesArray = new object[] {
        null,
        Name,
        Species_ID};
    rowAnimalRow.ItemArray = columnValuesArray;
    this.Rows.Add(rowAnimalRow);
    return rowAnimalRow;
}
```

Every time I try to run an imitation of this - I get InvalidCastException (Unable to cast object of type System.DataRow to type AnimalRow). As I would have expected.

So what makes their code more special?

Comment: what is your datatable? and AnimalDataTable? or a regular vanilla DataTable? the above relies on the overridden `NewRow`, etc.

Comment: also... typed datatables.... YMMV, but IMO (very subjective) you should try to just use a regular class here.

Comment: ... Designer.cs does not contain any overrides for `NewRow`. Do you think I should upload the whole auto-generated file? I don't think anyone would have the patience for that.

Comment: I'm testing a method that takes `IEnumerable<T> where T : DataRow`. IE, no touchy on the method. I'd love to kick all DataTables and their brethren out of the code base. No can do.

Comment: Could show us the code which causes the InvalidCastException pls?

Comment: @sq33G please don't (upload all). I haven't used typed datatables in a **really** long time, but I'm sure *somewhere* there is a line in there relating to AnimalRow - maybe via a typeof(...)

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz I think we can deduce: the NewRow line

Comment: actually, if you wanted to upload it to, say, pastie.org, we could see, without polluting the question?

Comment: Actually, you already answered. I'm testing and then I'll show you what the issue was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to @Marc Gravell for steering this in the right direction:

The `AnimalDataTable` class contains two overrides of undocumented* virtual methods of `DataTable`:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
protected override global::System.Data.DataRow NewRowFromBuilder(global::System.Data.DataRowBuilder builder) {
    return new AnimalRow(builder);
}

[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
protected override global::System.Type GetRowType() {
    return typeof(AnimalRow);
}
```

*<sub>[mostly undocumented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.getrowtype.aspx)</sub>