# Casting DataRow to Strongly-Typed DataRow

Tags: java, casting, datarow, jdesktop

I have a class that extends `DataRow`:

```
import org.jdesktop.dataset.DataRow;

public class MainDataRow extends DataRow {
  private MainDataTable baseDataTable;

  protected MainDataRow(MainDataTable dt) {
    super(dt);
    this.baseDataTable = dt;
  }

  public int    getId()                           { return (int)    super.getValue(baseDataTable.getColId()); };
  public void   setId(int id)                     {                 super.setValue(baseDataTable.getColId(), id); };
  public int    getDelta()                        { return (int)    super.getValue(baseDataTable.getColDelta()); };
  public void   setDelta(int delta)               {                 super.setValue(baseDataTable.getColDelta(), delta); };
  public String getNombre()                       { return (String) super.getValue(baseDataTable.getColNombre()); };
  public void   setNombre(String nombre)          {                 super.setValue(baseDataTable.getColNombre(), nombre); };
```

Also `MainDataTable` extends `DataTable`, and returns valid columns for `getColId()`, `getColDelta()`, `getColNombre()`.

I would like to do:

```
MainDataTable dt = new MainDataTable(ds);
MainDataRow dr = (MainDataRow) dt.appendRow();
```

But this is not possible due to a `CastClassException` (`dt.appendRow` return `DataRow` and `MainDataRow` is extending `DataRow`, not vice versa, so the only possibility could be something similar to `DataRow dr = (DataRow) new MainDataRow(dt);`).

In c++ it can be easyly achieved through `DataRowBuilder`, overriding `NewRowFromBuilder()` in `MainDataTable` and overriding the protected creator from `DataRowBuilder` in `MainDataRow` ([Casting DataRow to Strongly-Typed DataRow: How do they do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322679/casting-datarow-to-strongly-typed-datarow-how-do-they-do-it)).

How could I do it in Java?

**Edit**

MainDataTable class:

```
public class MainDataTable extends TypedDataTable<MainDataRow> {
...
}
```

And TypedDataTable class:

```
public abstract class TypedDataTable<TypeOfRow> extends DataTable {
  protected boolean locked;

  public TypedDataTable(DataSet ds, boolean appendRowSupported) {
    super(ds);
    InitClass();
    super.setAppendRowSupported(appendRowSupported);
    locked = false;
  }

  public Object clone() {
    try {
      return super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public abstract DataRow appendRow();
  @Override
  public abstract DataRow appendRowNoEvent();
  public abstract void InitVars();
  public abstract void InitClass();

  public boolean isLocked() {
    return locked;
  }

  public void setLocked(boolean locked) {
    this.locked = locked;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is suspicious. Usually method 'appendRow' appends row to a table, so it should have one input argument - `row` and `void` return result.

Comment: Not in swinglabs see[link]( http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/dataset/DataTable.html#appendRow())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `appendRow()` and `appendRowNoEvent()` in MainDataTable to return a MainDataRow

```
public abstract class TypedDataTable<TypeOfRow extends DataRow> extends DataTable {
  protected boolean locked;

  public TypedDataTable(DataSet ds, boolean appendRowSupported) {
    super(ds);
    InitClass();
    super.setAppendRowSupported(appendRowSupported);
    locked = false;
  }

  public Object clone() {
    try {
      return super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

 @Override
 public TypeOfRow appendRowNoEvent() {
     if (appendRowSupported) {
         TypeOfRow row = createDataRow(); //<-- HERE we create a MainDataRow!!!
         rows.add(row);
         return row;
     } else {
         return null;
     }
 }

 @Override
 public TypeOfRow appendRow() {
      return (TypeOfRow)super.appendRow();
 }

  public abstract TypeOfRow createDataRow();
  public abstract void InitVars();
  public abstract void InitClass();

  public boolean isLocked() {
    return locked;
  }

  public void setLocked(boolean locked) {
    this.locked = locked;
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds good. Is this method appending the returned row in the table? So when iterating through baseDataTable rows I can find the new appened rows. In fact, if you are sure of this, if you agree,  4th line should be: _MainDataRow row = new MainDataRow(this)_

Comment: @Miguel I found the original code of DataTable and I updated my post to show you exactly how you can make this work.

Comment: the first you provided worked, what is in solution now doesn't work because appendRow can not be casted to MainDataRow (it throws CastClassException). Thanks to you I reached the solution I'm going to post in a few. +1 for this if you could undo the edit and post previous response.

Comment: @Miguel Have you overriden both methods? You should not get a ClassCastException in that case. In DataTable, the method that creates the DataRow is appendRowNoEvent. Since we override it to create a MainDataRow, we can safely cast it. See the original code  here: http://kickjava.com/src/org/jdesktop/dataset/DataTable.java.htm My edit is actually a better way to do things since you don't have to worry about firing events. All you have to do is create a row and add it to the rows List

Comment: I can't make your code working when MainDataTable extends TypedDataTable<MainDataRow> (edited the post to attach TypedDataTable. Anyway it works with your previous solution.

Comment: I edited the question and put TyedDataTable<MainDataRow>. When adding appendRow to the MainDataTable, it says *"Cannot directly invoke the abstract method appendRow() for the type TypedDataTable<TonadsDataRow>"* I don't see how could I reach DataTable.appendRow with a TypedDataTable in the middle. (Well, only not declaring them in TypedDataTable, but I doesn't like too much because allows to make mistakes...) I agree with you that this is cleaner not having to worry about firing events.

Comment: @Miguel I updated my post again to show how to make this work